# Reduce boilerplate with function composition

Tags: scala

I have the following code :

```
def a = f(aa)
def b = f(bb)
def c = f(cc)
def d = f(dd)
```

Is there a solution to remove the boilerplate, i.e. explicit call to `f`

Comment: I’d be interested to know why you consider it boilerplate. How could you possibly write this in a more concise or clearer way? Soon people are going to find that the `def` keyword is boilerplate, too! :-P

Comment: Because the same pattern (call to f) appears multiple times, but I agree, it's just a few boilerplate and perhaps it's not possible to do better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something like this with the standard library:

```
val List(a,b,c,d) = List(aa,bb,cc,dd).map(f)
```

It uses pattern matching to assign the values on the left, which will fail at runtime if the two `List`s aren't the same length.

Scalaz has a more type-safe option that uses tuples to ensure the number of values on the left and right are the same (checked at compile time):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
val (a,b,c,d) = (aa,bb,cc,dd).map(f)
```

Comment: `val List(a,b,c,d) = List(aa,bb,cc,dd).map(f)` is not leazy solution all a, b, c, .. will be executed in tha same time but `def a = f(aa)` and `def b = f(bb)` will execute in moment when it will call.

Comment: When I replace the standard solution by the scalaz solution, I got a compile error : [error] conf/routes:49: not enough arguments for method apply: (n: Int)models.EventType.Value in trait LinearSeqOptimized.
[error] Unspecified value parameter n.

Comment: Yury: true, and this would be an issue if `f` has side-effects. I can't think of anything similar that would get around that. Yann: I don't have enough context to diagnose what the problem with the scalaz solution is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use implicit:
http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html

```
val aa: Int = 1

// Let's say that your function f returns instance of C
def f(x: Int): C = ???

implicit class C(in: Int) {
  // Do whatever you need here ...
}

def a: C = aa
```

Comment: aa is in fact a function, here is the definition of f : `def f[A:Reads, B:Writes](g: A => B)`